# o setInterval() não estou conseguindo fazer ele funcionar

Tags: javascript, html5, css3, javascript-eventos

não estou conseguindo colocar o um tempo pois criei um **carousel** e queria colocar um intervalo de 4 segundos para iteração .

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="pt-br">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <title>Document</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="container">
      <div class="wall wall-1" id="wall-1">
        <a href="#wall-3">Voltar</a>
        <h1>carrosel numero - 1</h1>
        <a href="#wall-2">Avançar</a>
      </div>

      <div class="wall wall-2" id="wall-2">
        <a href="#wall-1">Voltar</a>
        <h1>carrosel numero - 2</h1>
        <a href="#wall-3">Avançar</a>
      </div>

      <div class="wall wall-3" id="wall-3">
        <a href="#wall-2">Voltar</a>
        <h1>carrosel numero - 3</h1>
        <a href="#wall-1">Avançar</a>
      </div>
    </div>
    <script>
      document.location = "#wall-1";
      var x = 1;
      setInterval(function () {
        x++;
        document.querySelector("#wall-1").id = "#wall-1" + x;
        if (x == "#wall-3") {
          clearInterval();
        }
      }, 4000);
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

> aparece esse erro Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'id' of null
> at index.html:34

```
.container {
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
}

.wall {
  display: none;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

/* Corzinha de fundo para diferenciar */
.wall-1 {
  background-color: #f00;
}
.wall-2 {
  background-color: #0f0;
}
.wall-3 {
  background-color: #00f;
}

.wall:target {
  display: block;
}
```

#### código CSS que mostra o carousel

Comment: no caso como colocaria .

Comment: Essa linha 34 que refere-se ao erro de id não encontrado seria qual parte exatamente ali do script?

Comment: seria essa parte declarada document.querySelector("#wall-1").id = "#wall-1" + x;

Comment: Faça um teste de mesa. Na primeira vez que você executa a sua função, você procura por um elemento com o `id` `wall-1`, então você concatena `x` no `id` desse elemento, resultando no `id` `wall-12`. Na segunda vez que você executa a função, você procura novamente pelo `id` `wall-1`, mas esse `id` não existe mais, ele foi alterado, por isso o erro.

Comment: eu coloquei wall- sem numero mas tb não deu certo

Comment: no caso eu tinha ido pela essa logica

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tem dois problemas ai

1. O intervalo da primeira chamada ele aponta corretamente para o #wall-1

```
document.querySelector("#wall-1").id // Te da o valor de: wall-1
document.querySelector("#wall-1").id = "#wall-1" + x 
// Seria wall-1 recebe "wall-1" + 1
// Então estaria id="#wall-11" assim te retornando o erro que não conseguiu obter id de núlo
```

Então na segunda chamada ele ficaria assim

```
wall-1 = "#wall-1" + 1 // o seu id estaria como id="#wall-11"
```

Assim nem mesmo chegando ao #wall-2, pois você está atribuindo uma string á um número
sem contar que o # vai junto no id="#..."

E também não faria muito sentido você tentar atribuir ID existente á um outro elemento..

```
document.location = "#wall-1";
      var atual = 1;
      setInterval(function () {
        atual++;
        let id = document.querySelector(`#wall-${atual}`).id // id == wall-2, na prox chamada id será wall-3, etc...
        if (atual == 3) {
          clearInterval();
        }
      }, 4000);
```

Desse jeito ele entra no intervalo, adiciona +1 ao atual sendo atual == 2

É bem ruim você fazer isso com Javascript Puro, a não ser que esteja aprendendo ainda, tente começar com Jquery[1], além de prático vai te dar uma ajuda com relação á animações/DOM em JS.